# Can Kettle be used to parse an email text file to a table?

Tags: parsing, email, kettle

I have several email in text format that I extracted into a directory using Kettle "Get Mails".  I need to parse each file into a table (.txt) with columns for:

Received time and date
Subject
From
Content

Is there an easy way to do this using Kettle?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the Job step "Get mails", use the Transformation step "Email messages input." Under the Fields option you can choose: Received date, Subject, Sender, and Body. This will create a row for each email which you can then send to your desired output step.